# How can I implement a transparent eraser tool in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

How can I implement an eraser in Flex so that when it erases on an mx:Image, it makes the area transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        protected function myImage_completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            trace("file loaded");
            var tempBdData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myImage.contentWidth,myImage.contentHeight,true);
            tempBdData.draw(myImage);
            (myImage.content as Bitmap).bitmapData = tempBdData;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Image
    id="myImage"
    source="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"
    complete="myImage_completeHandler(event)"
    mouseDown="(myImage.content as Bitmap).bitmapData.setPixel32(event.localX,event.localY,0x00000000)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to draw your image in a BitmapData object then use the function setPixel32 :

Example :

```
setPixel32 (coordX, coordY, 0x60FF0000);
```

where 0x60FF0000 is :

- 60 (alpha)
- FF (red)
- 00 (green)
- 00 (blue)

Comment: The Image has as a part of it's composition a BitmapData instance, if you have an image such as, example posted in separate answer for code.

Answer (score 1):

From most erase functions I've seen, not that many I'll admit, it doesn't turn something transparent, ( changing alpha ) , instead it paints with the background color.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to add a black mask image to your Image component (via the "mask" property), which will have no effect on the image initially, and then paint white into the mask image wherever the user clicks/drags within the image.  Hope that helps.